# How far back in time does a MongoDB change stream go?

Tags: mongodb, changestream

I considering using MongoDB change stream feature to replicate some data from one place to another. However, I am trying to figure out of I 1) first need to do a manual one-off copy (backfill), and *then* 2) initialise the change stream replication - or if the change stream simply will contain *all* data stored in MongoDB and automatically would copy all relevant data (that is, would imply backfilling).

Comment: Normally, one uses replica-sets for data replication.

Comment: Okay, and how far in back does the replica-set go? Is it like in Raft where the log always contain the history of all changes?

Comment: Reference: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/replication/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change stream [uses the oplog](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/#change-streams). Since MongoDB 4.4, [it can be configured to keep the oplog for at least](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/#replica-set-oplog)

- X number of time duration.
- Y amount of data (bytes).

That is, one cannot use MongoDB change stream for backpropagation. Instead, backpropagation needs to happen through paginating through the actual data using the fetch API.